React Native mobile app's icon isn't seem properly when installed
I created my first mobile app, I used expo. I have app.json file but it doesn't change the icon of my app nor the splashscreen (in development mode it works, after building it doesn't work). Below I am leaving app.json file, can you please tell me if I am doing something wrong or need to do something else?
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "izmir-burada",
    "slug": "izmir-burada",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "izmir burada",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.ozan1535.izmirburada"
    },
    "plugins": ["expo-router"],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "d57fdd39-8bc8..."
      }
    }
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-..."
  }

